# sublimevideo player load too slow on safari iphone5

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video

I have sublimevideo integrated into web and mobile version of my site. I have desktop and iphone connected to the same network but seems like on iphone the video load is too slow comparing to desktop version.

I am not sure what is the root cause of this. It might cause by safari on IOS7/IOS8 ?

Please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved this problem.

1. My video mime type was not set to video/mp4
2. I have a lazy load image jQuery plugin. after disabling it it work. this might not be the case for you.

From my experience, you better first try to test your video with sublimevideo in isolation by disabling other third parties libs. this can help you to make sure that sublimevideo does work.

please check it here https://getsatisfaction.com/sublimevideo/topics/sublimevideo_loading_very_slow_on_iphone5_even_sometimes_have_to_click_twice_to_launch_the_player_but_iphone4_ipad_and-o94jr

Answer (score 1):

Could you make a jsfiddle or jsbin to demonstrate the problem? Can you reproduce the behavior in the simulator or only on real devices?

Unfortunately, SublimeVideo has had poor iOS support since they were acquired by DailyMotion in December 2013, and I have started migrating my clients to other players instead.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question with your solution.